# How to tell which version of R I'm running when two versions are installed

Tags: r, version, built-in

There are two R directories on my computer:
one is `/home/R-2.15.2`,the other is `/home/R-2.15.1`,
when I input `R` , I can start R, now I want to know which R is running: 2.15.1 or 2.15.2?

Comment: When you start R, a bunch of text should appear. That text should include the version number

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Run `R --version` there's info about version on the first line.

Edit: If you ask this question then I bet that R is not running from any of these directories. Check $PATH env variable to get information where binaries are looked for and in which order.

Edit 2: Use `type` shell command to find where binary for given command is stored, `-a` for all paths, `-f` for the hashed one (basically: most recently used).

Answer (score 77):

05/20/2021 Update:

In the R terminal, type `R.version`.

---

<s>In addition to @Piotr Jaszkowski, `R.Version()` should do the work as well</s>

Comment: It's `R.version`.

Answer (score 30):

The builtin `version` will show this.

```
> version
               _                            
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0     
...
version.string R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
```

`version` is a named list with 14 items, really you just want to see:

```
> version[['version.string']]
               _                            
[1] "R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)"
```

and in fact **if you only want the version-string**:

```
> strsplit(version[['version.string']], ' ')[[1]][3]
[1] "2.15.2"
```

Type `builtins()` to see all the builtins.

POSTSCRIPT: turns out `version` and  `R.version` (mentioned by [nathaninmac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549040/nathaninmac)) are aliases for the same thing.

Comment: It might appear simple, but its output is a 14-part formatted string...

Comment: Following nathaninmac's answer, `paste(version[c("major", "minor")], collapse = ".")` is another way to get the version string `2.15.2`

Answer (score 10):

Try `sessionInfo()`

Next to the R version it also returns the versions of the loaded packages and more.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/sessionInfo.html

Answer (score 7):

This will do the trick as well

```
paste0(R.Version()[c("major","minor")], collapse = ".")
```

Comment: or paste0(R.version$major,".",R.version$minor)

Answer (score 3):

Nobody listed `getRversion()` so far, which has the advantage that you can make comparisons with its return value. For example:

```r
getRversion()
#> [1] '4.3.0'
getRversion() >= "4.3.0"
#> [1] TRUE

checkmate::assert_true(getRversion() >= "4.3.0")
checkmate::assert_true(getRversion() >= "4.3.1")
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): Assertion on 'getRversion() >= "4.3.1"' failed: Must be TRUE.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can type 'which R' to which R binary gets used

or type R and see something like below, that should tell you which version.

"
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) -- "Roasted Marshmallows"
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
..
..
"