# programmatically find the current version of R

Tags: r

In R, one can figure out the version of a specific package, and use relational operators on it, with `packageVersion()`.  For example:

```
packageVersion("MASS")
(pp <- packageVersion("MASS"))
## [1] ‘7.3.43’ 
pp > '7.2.0'
## TRUE
```

How does one get the equivalent form of version information for the running copy of R itself?

To answer this, you have to figure out exactly where to look, which is not as easy as it seems: for example

```
grep("R[._vV]",apropos("version"),value=TRUE)
## [1] ".ess.ESSRversion" ".ess.Rversion"    "getRversion"       
## "R_system_version"
## [5] "R.Version"        "R.version"        "R.version.string"
```

I'm asking this because I'm frustrated at having to figure it out every few months ... I will answer if no-one else does.  Extra credit for elucidating the difference between `packageVersion()` and `package_version()` ...

I think this question is answered in passing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983069), but the focus of my question is specifically how to get the information in **programmatic** form (i.e., not just how to find out what version is running, but how to get it in a form suitable for running automated version tests within R).

Comment: possible duplicate of [which version of R is running in my computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983069/which-version-of-r-is-running-in-my-computer)

Comment: @smci - I disagree. It's not an exact duplicate - Ben wants more than just a print out of what version is being run.

Comment: @Dason: that's not what the other question asked for, and it's not what the [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15983118/202229) gave. Mine , for example. Which was IMO better than the accepted answer. Anyway: how to canonicalize questions on this topic?

Comment: @smci The linked question says "now i want to know which R is running ,2.15.1 or 2.15.2" and in no way indicates that they need to programmatically compare the version numbers.

Comment: @Dason: the question also in no way says they don't want to programmatically compare them. Nor does it preclude them from just using `R --version` on a command line either. It's an open question. In my answer there I showed them how to programmatically access them.

Comment: @smci I'm just saying that in my view I don't think that question is an exact duplicate.  That question leaves open the possibility of them not being programmatically compared. This question wants them to be programmatically compared.  I'm not trying to start an argument - just stating my opinion.  And it seems like this only has one close vote (which I assume is yours?) so I can't be the only one that doesn't think it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are documented in the `?R.Version` help page. It depends on exactly how you want the value formatted/stored really.

`packageVersion()` extracts the version info from a particular package as a `package_version` object.

`package_version()` essentially parses a version number into a `package_version` value that can be easily compared.

You can compare versions with

```
package_version(R.version) > package_version("3.0.1")
```

or something like that.

The `getRversion()` function pointed to in the `?R.Version` help page automatically returns a `package_version` object.

```
getRversion() > package_version("3.0.1")
```

Plus the `package_version` objects can do automatic conversion with conformable strings as well

```
getRversion() > "3.0.1"
```

Comment: TMTOWTDI = There's more than one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the `version` constant gives you that info. In my case:

```
version
## platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
## arch           x86_64                      
## os             linux-gnu                   
## system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
## status                                     
## major          3                           
## minor          2.2                         
## year           2015                        
## month          08                          
## day            14                          
## svn rev        69053                       
## language       R                           
## version.string R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
## nickname       Fire Safety            
with(version, paste(major, minor, sep='.'))
## [1] "3.2.2"
```